# include file ,exclude file - permission clarification hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

I am new to hadoop . 
using Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.0.0

In the process of  adding and decommission of datanode in multi node cluster .
Read about the steps in the book. 
I really got stuck in the middle as to what permission(user:group) should be set for include and exclude file which should reside on the local system of the namenode running .
Also it will be much helpful if anyone can give me a example as to how include and exclude file will look. 
I assume we just need to add the Network address of the datanode cluster in each of the file.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured out myself , please ignore it . 
created the file with a sudo and was able to fix the error. my bad.

include file should contains the Network address of the nodes that are allowed to connected to the namenode 
exclude file is just the opposite of include file .

Thanks